# Ionic 3 not updating view

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

Hi I got a function which will update after a http request to the server. It seems that the console.log show that the value has been updated but the UI is not updating unless I click on any other component(ex. input).

This is my function:

```
fileTransfer.upload(this.created_image, upload_url, options)
.then((data) => {
    console.log("success:"+data.response); //This is showing correct response
    var obj = JSON.parse(data.response);
    this.sv_value = obj.value;
    console.log(this.sv_value); //This is showing correct value
}, (err) => {
    console.log("failure:");
})
```

This is my view html:

```
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col center width-100 no-padding>
        <h2>{{sv_value}}</h2> //This is not updated
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
```

Is there any way I can tackle this issue? Thank you

Comment: but you log this.value nit sv_value

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @mohamadrabee Sorry it's a question typo. Edited

Comment: @robbannn Yeah i marked it as the best answer. Thanks!. Is this a common way of updating value in UI in Angular 2?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Try placing `this.sv_value = obj.value;` inside `NgZone.run();` to make Angular detect the change.

```
import { Component, NgZone } from "@angular/core";
...

export class MyComponentPage {
    constructor(
        private zone: NgZone
        ...
    ){ }

    yourFunction(){
        fileTransfer.upload(this.created_image, upload_url, options)
        .then((data) => {
            console.log("success:"+data.response); //This is showing correct response
            var obj = JSON.parse(data.response);

            this.zone.run(() => {
                this.sv_value = obj.value;
            });

            console.log(this.value); //This is showing correct value
        }, (err) => {
            console.log("failure:");
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, may I ask something? Is this a common way of updating value in UI in Angular 2? thanks

Comment: @RedzwanLatif is this still your solution? In my case the view is only not rendered if we use it on mobile device, no problems with ionic serve, did you had the same behavior?

Comment: Hi! Can I ask you about the performance? I've tried this workaround but the performance has decreased.

Comment: Worked for me  Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

I was facing the exact same issue in Ionic 4 and this is how I fixed it:

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

constructor(private changeRef: ChangeDetectorRef)

fileTransfer.upload(this.created_image, upload_url, options)
.then((data) => {
    console.log("success:"+data.response); //This is showing correct response
    var obj = JSON.parse(data.response);
    this.sv_value = obj.value;
    console.log(this.sv_value); //This is showing correct value
    this.changeRef.detectChanges(); // ---> Add this here
}, (err) => {
    console.log("failure:");
})
```

Essentially by using `detectChanges()`, we are forcing the platform to detect the changes and kick them into the UI.