# Ionic 4 component not rendering until a change happens. Works in chrome but not through Ionic DevApp

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I created a component called `IsiComponent` and I am including the module file in one of my pages module file which looks like

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';

import { CalculatorPage } from './calculator.page';
import { IsiModule } from '../isi/isi.module';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: CalculatorPage
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
    IsiModule
  ]
})
export class CalculatorPageModule {}
```

The IsiComponent module file:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { IsiComponent } from './isi.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
  ],
  declarations: [IsiComponent],
  exports: [IsiComponent]
})
export class IsiModule {}
```

In my calculator page html file I initiate the component via

```
<ion-footer>
  <app-isi></app-isi>
</ion-footer>
```

When I open my page, the component doesn't render until I do some interaction with something on the screen like, focus an input or select a radio button. Any idea why that would be happening?

Oh also, it renders fine when I am testing in chrome. It isn't rendering using the Ionic DevApp on my iphone.

I found this post which sounds like the same behavior, but it looks like we are doing different things [Ionic 3 not updating view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45690368/ionic-3-not-updating-view)

Comment: My suggestion would be to state at the top that it works in Chrome but not the DevApp as that is a key consideration when reading through the rest of the question.

Comment: @DeborahK thank you for the suggestion. I have edited my title

Comment: How are you rendering the component / page? Is there an async operation, such as an API request retrieving data prior to render?